# Remove users from AD group if they do not exist in CSV

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have a task where we have a .csv file containing users. The contents of the CSV should be compared against an AD security group.  Any user that is **NOT** in the CSV needs to be removed from the AD group.

In the past I have added/removed users from groups that ARE listed in the CSV file, but have no idea how to remove them if they are not in the CSV.

Will I have to use one script to dump the members of the group to a file, compare this file against the CSV which would then create a file of the users in the group but not in the CSV, and then use that as my source to remove the users?

Answer (score 2):

Create a list from the relevant user attribute in the CSV (e.g. the distinguished name). Get the group members that are not present in this list using a `Where-Object` filter with the `-notcontains` operator. Then remove those members from the group.

Example:

```
$validUsers   = Import-Csv 'C:\path\to\your.csv' | Select-Object -Expand dn

$invalidUsers = Get-ADGroupMember 'groupname' |
                Where-Object { $validUsers -notcontains $_.distinguishedName }

Remove-ADGroupMember 'groupname' $invalidUsers -WhatIf
```

Remove the `-WhatIf` switch to actually remove the group members instead of doing a dry-run.